# Load a different user control than the one currently being loaded

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

My ASP.NET application supports its own version of themes (not the standard ASP.NET themes). There is a single folder that contains all of the user controls used by the application's pages. I would like to provide a way to **optionally** 'override', for lack of a better term, these user controls through a controls folder in the theme.

The challenge is that the application pages, not the theme files, are what reference the user controls. The behavior that I would like is that when a control of the same name exists in the theme controls folder it will be loaded instead of the normal control. I'd like to achieve this without altering the application pages (i.e. their register directives).

What is the best way to achieve this? It seems like I should be able to use a base class for my user controls that will check for a theme-specific version of the control and, if it exists, stop loading itself and load the other control instead.

The function below is a crude attempt to achieve my goal. While the page does load the desired user control instead, ASP.NET is still processing both user controls event handlers (e.g. Init, PreRender, Load, etc) in full under the hood. I want to abort processing this control to reduce load on the server.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists("~/themes/mytheme/controls/mycontrol.ascx")
    {
        this.

        UserControl ctrl =    this.LoadControl("~/themes/mytheme/controls/mycontrol.ascx");
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
}

public void RemoveAllEventHandlers()
{
    RemoveAllEventHandlers(this);
}
public static void RemoveAllEventHandlers(Control ctrl)
{
    if (ctrl != null) {
        Type ctrlType = ctrl.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propInfo = ctrlType.GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        EventHandlerList handlerList = (EventHandlerList)propInfo.GetValue(ctrl, null);
        FieldInfo headInfo = handlerList.GetType.GetField("head", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Dictionary<object, Delegate[]> handlerDict = new Dictionary<object, Delegate[]>();
        object head = headInfo.GetValue(handlerList);
        if (head != null) {
            Type entry = head.GetType();
            FieldInfo handlerFI = entry.GetField("handler", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            FieldInfo keyFI = entry.GetField("key", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            FieldInfo nextFI = entry.GetField("next", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            HelpAddEntry(handlerDict, head, handlerFI, keyFI, nextFI);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<object, Delegate[]> pair in handlerDict) {
                for (int x = pair.Value.Length - 1; x >= 0; x += -1) {
                    handlerList.RemoveHandler(pair.Key, pair.Value[x]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void HelpAddEntry(Dictionary<object, Delegate[]> dict, object entry, FieldInfo handlerFI, FieldInfo keyFI, FieldInfo nextFI)
{
    Delegate del = (Delegate)handlerFI.GetValue(entry);
    object key = keyFI.GetValue(entry);
    object nxt = nextFI.GetValue(entry);
    Delegate[] listeners = del.GetInvocationList();
    if (listeners != null && listeners.Length > 0) {
        dict.Add(key, listeners);
    }
    if (nxt != null) {
        HelpAddEntry(dict, nxt, handlerFI, keyFI, nextFI);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I was able to prevent the original control's event handlers from running using the updated code above. However, there is a fundamental flaw with this approach: there's a parent/child relationship between these two controls, not a replacement. So, any properties that are set on the parent control are not passed to the child control (though I'm sure this could be done with Reflection) and the HTML ID values of the child control are different (i.e. they're pre-pended with the ID of the parent control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much more elegant way to solve this problem by 'rewriting' the control's Src attribute in the page directive. The beauty of this is that it is done *before* ASP.NET even parses the page. To do this you create a class that inherits from PageParserFilter. Then in the  node of the Web.config file you can set the pageParserFilterType attribute to the newly created class so now all pages of the site will run through the new class.

Answer (score 0):

Few things are missing here. Try this instead:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "~/themes/mytheme/controls/mycontrol.ascx";
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)))
    {
        UserControl ctrl = (UserControl)this.LoadControl("~/themes/mytheme/controls/mycontrol.ascx");
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
    else 
    {

        //Load Other controls

    }

}
```

Comment: Good catch on the missing Server.MapPath. I hadn't tested the File.Exists code before posting that here. Anyway, the main problem that I'm trying to solve is how stop loading the current control (and its event handlers) and only load the new control to save on server load/processing.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need to load those controls if they exist, else load other controls. Then why don't put the code to load other controls in else part?

Comment: The Page_Init function that I posted is from the first control (we'll call this the 'default' control), not the page. The pages that use these user controls manually reference the controls using register directives so unless there's some way to override which control the page actually loads then I have to do this 'handoff' from inside the default control (when the theme control exists).

Comment: I would use placeholders in the page and load controls in placeholders. I believe only registering those controls would not take noticeable resource. So I would not care much if they are registered and not used.